# GPU Rendering with AMD RADEON R9 M395X

Tags: rendering

I am new to this forum and pretty much new to blender rendering.

When I initially started, I could render with GPU, but now I can only do it with my CPU, which I don't prefer.

When I try the GPU, my blender goes slow/freezes and it would take way too long to finish.

Here are my iMac Specs

macOS Sierra
iMac Retina 5k, 27in, Late 2015
Processor 4 GHz Intel Core i7
32 GB 1867 MHz DDR3
Graphics AMD Radeon R9 M395X 4096 MB

Is there something I need to do or install, or does blender not support what I have :-/

Thanks!

Comment: Radeon R9 have a long history of problems with blender. see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=R9  most of them seem to point at the drivers for such cards. Search through those questions for a possible solution.

Comment: Appreciate your help and prompt response!

Comment: "*When I initially started, I could render with GPU, but now I can only do it with my CPU*" What have you done in the meantime, or what changes that might have caused it to stop working?

Comment: I wish I could remember. I stopped using it for a couple of months and when I went to render a project again, it started working differently.

Comment: I use different Radeons and especially different R9s on several computers (Windows and Linux) without problems. Most likely a MacOS update, since it's quite common that Apple breaks small things with big consequences. I developed a small audio tool for MacOS and abandoned it (and Apple/MacOS in general) in 2009 because of those update issues.